# obsolete /System/Library/dyld files for deletion?

Tags: macos, monterey

I trying to free space on my 2015 Macbook Pro,  Monteray 12.2.1, 250gb ssd

My system data is up to 115gb which seems crazy.

I've found several files in the /System/Library/dyld dir that look suspicious.

```
/System/Library/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_arm64e
```

size 1.5gb

```
/System/Library/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_arm64e.1
```

size 1.4gb

I'm aware the file without the .1 extension is required, but is the one with the ".1" extension also required?

I'm guessing it may be an older/obsolete version?

There are several other files with these numeric extensions...

[image: /System/Library/dyld]

Any advice about other places to look is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I would be wary of taking "About This Mac"'s Storage indicator of the size of System data. I would suggest using a tool like OmniDiskSweeper to sort your disk by size, and see what's taking up space.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Even if it's tempting, I would strongly recommend against deleting files in that folder. The most obvious reason is that `/System/Library/dyld` is protected by SIP, that is, macOS expects those files to be there - deleting them could have unexpected consequences and prevent your Mac from running properly. The other reason is that some of the "obsolete" files _are indeed in use_: running `sudo lsof | egrep 'dyld_shared.*[1|2|3]'` on my Mac listed Evernote, ReceiverHelper and Citrix Workspace Launcher. (The files in the screenshot match the files present on my Mac.)